# BigQuery: 2 tables - 1 for inserts + 1 for selects?

Tags: google-bigquery

can anyone interpret a BQ doc [Real-time dashboards and queries section](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#usecases) for me?

1. if we have 2 BQ tables (one for inserts + one for selects), *does it make selects perform noticeably faster*?
2. what does *reconciliation* mean? is it *coalescing* i.e. internal BQ defragmentation of table? if not - does it mean "a clean up process" during replication to reconciled table?
3. section speaks about 2 BQ tables - reconciled & non-reconciled. How replication between them can be implemented?
4. does *truncating* mean the [`WRITE_TRUNCATE` job setting](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs)? if so, how such truncate that should happen after tables replication step is synchronized with `insertAll` that may happen meanwhile on unreconciled table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page can likely use a bit of clarification (I've filed a doc bug to do so). The part that you are mentioning came from an early design document.

The scenario that section is trying to deal with is when you have a read-write datastore (such as appengine DataStore) that you want to use BigQuery with. You can periodically dump the state of that datastore to one table to create a snapshot of the datastore in time, and then stream updates to a second table. The second table can be considered deltas from the original table. You can construct your queries in such a way that the modified rows from the streaming table will take precedence over the values in the snapshot table. This is really somewhat advanced usage, and shouldn't be considered if you just want to build a basic dashboard.

If you are only dealing with data that is written once and never updated, you don't need to follow the guidelines in this section at all... just use `insertAll` to a single table.

Comment: Jordan, thx, you're extremely helpful in these clarifs. Can you give me more hint: we have a BQ table, we insert and select from it (surely, never update - BQ seems not to support updates). Will the replication of this table into "live inserts table" & "query-only table" make the "query-only table" selects faster? Or this separation would be irrelevant and performace woulde be the same as selecting from our current "insert-select" table?

Comment: No, separating your data into multiple tables will not be likely to improve your query performance.

Comment: Jordan one more :)... If we use a lot of `insertAlls`, sometimes inserting small amount of records with it, does it have a negative impact on underlying BQ store fragmentation and hence - on duration of selects being run? Or we're OK and `insertAll` is optimized to handle such non-bulk usage?